# how to convert items of array into array themselves Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My problem is that I've got this array:

```
np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -1.2, -3.4, -3.4, -4.5, -4.5])
```

and I want to convert the elements to array like this:

```
np.array([[0.0], [0.0], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
```

So is there a loop or a numpy function that I could use to do this task?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or simply:

```
arr[:,None]

# array([[ 0. ],
#        [ 0. ],
#        [-1.2],
#        [-1.2],
#        [-3.4],
#        [-3.4],
#        [-4.5],
#        [-4.5]])
```

Comment: Same as `a1[:,np.newaxis]`. `None` in a `np` slice is synonymous to `np.newaxis`

Comment: @utkarsh13 Honestly, I can't explain this better than the doc http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis. Basically, None means creating a newaxis here.

Comment: @OrB Works on Python 2 as well.

Comment: @Psidom OK, I thought it should work for any list. Turns out it works for numpy arrays only.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> a1 = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -1.2, -3.4, -3.4, -4.5, -4.5])
>>> np.array([[x] for x in a1])
array([[ 0. ],
       [ 0. ],
       [-1.2],
       [-1.2],
       [-3.4],
       [-3.4],
       [-4.5],
       [-4.5]])
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Isn't this just a [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) operation from row to column vector?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -1.2, -3.4, -3.4, -4.5, -4.5])
In [3]: np.reshape(x, (-1,1))
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0. ],
       [ 0. ],
       [-1.2],
       [-1.2],
       [-3.4],
       [-3.4],
       [-4.5],
       [-4.5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) functions:

- [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html#numpy-expand-dims) - **the explicit option**

  ```
  >>> import numpy as np
  >>> a = np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -1.2, -3.4, -3.4, -4.5, -4.5])

  >>> np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)
  array([[ 0. ], [ 0. ], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
  ```
- slicing with [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) (which is an alias for `None`)

  ```
  >>> np.array(a)[:, np.newaxis]
  array([[ 0. ], [ 0. ], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
  >>> np.array(a)[:, None]
  array([[ 0. ], [ 0. ], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
  ```

Instead of adding an `axis` manually you can also use some default ways to create a multidimensional array and then swap the axis, for example with [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html#numpy-transpose) but you could also use [`np.swapaxes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html#numpy-swapaxes) or [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape):

- [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) with ndmin=2

  ```
  >>> np.array([0.0, 0.0, -1.2, -1.2, -3.4, -3.4, -4.5, -4.5], ndmin=2).T
  array([[ 0. ], [ 0. ], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
  ```
- [`np.atleast_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array) and

  ```
  >>> np.atleast_2d(a).swapaxes(1, 0)
  array([[ 0. ], [ 0. ], [-1.2], [-1.2], [-3.4], [-3.4], [-4.5], [-4.5]])
  ```